# Report folders which have a specific subfolder

Tags: powershell, path, powershell-3.0

I am building a script which I use to deploy files to multiple specific folders.
The destination folders are collected using this part.

```
$destinations = Get-ChildItem "C:\this\is\*\my\path\"
```

So my script replaces only if the folder has the subfolders "\my\path\"

If I now check my variable it will return the fullpathes but I only need the folder name. I tried using `select -path` to show at least only the path but it returned as well the length, mode etc.

my goal is to return only values like this:

```
folder 1
folder 2
folder 3
```

I am using powershell 3.0

Comment: Do you only want the folders represented by the `*` then? The grandparent folder of `\path`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if we are checking for folders that have the child structure `folder1\folder2` where the parent folder is in `C:\Temp` then we would do something like this:

```
$destinations = (Get-Item "C:\Temp\*\folder1\folder2").Parent.Parent.Name
```

`Get-Item "C:\Temp\*\folder1\folder2"` would just return `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` objects for `folder2`. We take those objects and find their grandparent folders and just return their names only.

Comment: ah this seems to make sense. Thank you, I will do a check later when I am home, but looks promising